# Como forçar um dispositivo móvel a pedir site para computador

Tags: php

Tenho um site que está otimizado tanto para dispositivos moveis como para desktop. Acontece que em alguns dispositivos móveis aparece o seguinte erro:

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

No entanto se eu pedir o site para computador ele já deixa correr o site. Existe alguma forma de meter o site pré predefinido para correr em versão computador. Ou alguma outra solução?
Obrigado.
Atualização:
Aqui está o código:

```
   <html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
     charset=ibm866" > <meta name = "viewport" content= "width=device=width, 
     initial-scale=1">
       <title>Meusite</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="width: 100%; 
    text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="img/vendas.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
        <!--<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="img/mini.JPG" style="width: 100%;" />
            <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="img/miniII.JPG" style="width: 100%;" />-->


        <div style="text-align: right; font-family: Arial;"></div>
        </div>


        <div style="text-align: center;"><br />
        &nbsp;</div>

        <div style="text-align: center;"><a 
         href="http://www.omeusite.pt/1038/omeusite.php"><img alt="" 
         src="img/Meusite.png" style="border: 0px solid ; width: 220px; " />
          </a><br />
        &nbsp;
        <div style="text-align: right;"><a href="tel:932222222"><img alt="" 
          src="img/tel.png" style="border: 0px solid ; width: 61px; height: 
          61px;" /></a></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


 <p></p>
 </body>
```

Comment: o codigo? mostra ele

Comment: Já editei o original

Comment: Pelo vista nada com relação ao código, e sim dos navegadores desses mobiles que acusam o erro. Pode passar o link pra que eu abra no meu mobile?